# how to initialize private static final from autowired service

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have faced a situation where `@scheduled` annotation is used.

When I have the value on the class it works :

```java
private static final String CRON = "0 0 0 * * ?";

@Scheduled(cron = CRON)
public void scheduledMethod(){}
```

But My requirement is to load this `CRON` expression from an `autowired service` :

```java
 @Autowired
 private ParamService paramService;

 private static final String CRON = paramService.get("cron");
```

`paramService.get("cron")` read variable named `cron` from database.

This is not working due to the `static context`. Also, I should have the variable as **static final String**. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: That's not possible. What does paramService.get("cron"); do?

Comment: This will simply never work for various reasons, but the most prevaling is that the language simply doesn't allow it (non-static access in a static context). Yes let Spring manage your properties and use `@Scheduled(cron = "${cron}")`.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it fetches the actual value from db

Comment: In that case you should use the TaskScheduler to schedule it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do using [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) syntax

```java
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Scheduled(cron = "#{paramService.get('cron')}")
    public void scheduledMethod() {
        ... do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I have to parseInt paramService.get('delay') like variable?

Comment: I guess it should be something like "#{Integer.parseInt(paramService.get('delay'))}"